# Nested components with [AutoComplete]

Tags: transactions, com+, servicedcomponent

Let's assume that  I got two `ServiceComponent` classes which I use like this:

```
using (var outer = new MyComponent1())
{
    string data;
    using (var inner = new MyComponent2())
    {
        data = inner.GetFromQueue();
    }

    outer.Process(data);
}
```

Both `MyComponent1` and `MyComponent2` uses the `[AutoComplete]` attributes on their methods.

Will `MyComponent2` commit when being disposed or will it wait on the transaction started by `MyComponent1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AutoComplete` is not required. COM+ works fine as long as you let exceptions propagate up the call stack.

Just make sure that all components are disposed properly or the transactions will timeout.